# how to load the comment template from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, comments, comment-form

I want to create custom design for the comments. 
`comments_template()` will load the default `\comments.php`.

i have a file inside my plugin `commentsnew.php` how can i use this file for `comments_template()`?

file is getting loaded relative to theme directory.

`apply_filters( 'comments_template', string $theme_template )` this completely overrides the template but don't want a complete override but apply only if used.

Comment: Can you provide some context for why you would want to do this or the problem that this solves?

Comment: @TomJNowell to have a review template for the custom post that is created inside a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `comments_template` filter to alter which file your CPT will use for comments.

```
function wpse_plugin_comment_template( $comment_template ) {
     global $post;
     if ( !( is_singular() && ( have_comments() || 'open' == $post->comment_status ) ) ) {
        // leave the standard comments template for standard post types
        return;
     }
     if($post->post_type == 'business'){ // assuming there is a post type called business
        // This is where you would use your commentsnew.php, or review.php
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/review.php';
     }
}
// throw this into your plugin or your functions.php file to define the custom comments template.
add_filter( "comments_template", "wpse_plugin_comment_template" );
```

Comment: Thank you . but this completely overrides the template for the post type` business` but i needed a case where `business` can have multiple comments templates and and use them as needed

Comment: You should be able to use this same model, changing the "if" statement to whatever criteria you require for your workflow.  For that matter, you could have multiple comments templates, and swap among them using a `switch ... case` statement to select which to use.  In any case, `add_filter()` would get the process started for you.

Comment: got it thank you :)